# Single page dashboard architecture

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, javascript

I am implementing a dashboard. I figured I'd make it work like a SPA for cleaner flow and better performance. When you click a sidebar link, the page/section gets loaded with AJAX. You can still browse the URL for each page, loading the whole thing.

I'm unhappy with the architecture I chose, and that's because of my lack of familiarity with modular js. This is how it works:

```
let Dashboard = (function () {
   // ...

   let load = html => {
    $container.html(html);
    CurrentPage.init();
   }

   let requestAndLoad = url => $.get(url, html => load(html));

   let openPage = $link => requestAndLoad($link.attr('href')).done(() => updateURL());

   return {
    init: () => {
        $sidebar.find('a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            openPage($(this));
        });
    },
    setCurrentPage: page => {....}
   }
})();
```

When the HTML is loaded (clicking sidebar link or browsing to the URL), we set `CurrentPage` so the corresponding `init` function is called, e.g:

```
Dashboard.setCurrentPage('USERS');
```

I think it is a pretty awkward way to initialize a page. Suggestions?

Then comes the part where we have different modules to handle each page. You will see a lack of DRY principles. I'm going to present forward a couple of them, so you get the idea. This would be inside `Dashboard`:

```
let Home = (function () {
    const name = 'HOME';
    let pageURL = null;

    return {
        init: () => {...},
        load: () => requestAndLoad(pageURL),
        setURL: url => pageURL = url,
        getURL: () => pageURL,
        getName: () => name
    }
})();

let Users = (function () {
    const name = 'USERS';
    let pageURL = null;

    return {
        init: () => {...},
        load: () => requestAndLoad(pageURL),
        setURL: url => pageURL = url,
        getURL: () => pageURL,
        getName: () => name
    }
})();
```

Now, coming from an OOP background, there would be an obvious base class and all pages would inherit this one. This is the js alternative I've thought about, but I'm not sure this is advised:

```
let Page = (name, pageURL) => {
    let init;
    return {
        init: () => init,
        load: () => requestAndLoad(pageURL),
        setURL: url => pageURL = url,
        getURL: () => pageURL,
        getName: () => name
    }
};

let Users = Page('USERS', usersURL);
Users.init = () => {...};
```

Having a base object and then overriding some function from an outer scope doesn't seem an ideal solution.

This has zero extensibility if I need to add a new page or worse, the need that has arised now, a page within a page or rather an "extended" page; i.e. I would like to make the "user profile" (specific user) page "browsable", which would require having a new page object to handle it, initialize components, update URL... With the current architecture that'd be an awful lot of work and would bloat the monster even further.

To clarify, the point of all these `init` functions would be running your typical "onload" actions, like initializing widgets and binding event listeners. Typically ran after loading some HTML. The expression `something.init()` keeps repeating in my code and I don't like it. If there is a more standard and proper way of doing such a thing in js development please let me know.

Back to the topic: I took a similar approach with other modules used within some pages. For instance, `Draft` is used both in the `Emails` and `Users` page. Initially, it only existed in `Emails`, but when the need of loading a draft in the `Users` page came up I rolled out a "child class". However, its behavior is of course different.

- In the emails page the draft would is displayed as a panel in the page and some of its interactions were showing a preview when clicking the "save" button, or going back to the inbox when clicking the "back" button.
- In the users page the draft is displayed as a modal. Some of its interactions are different, like showing a preview modal when saving it or simply closing the modal (there is no "back" button).

An OOP solution is evident here, I just "can't" do it with js. Some parts of the behavior are common, while some others are slightly different (subclass). Here's my approach:

```
let Emails = (function () {
    const name = 'MESSAGES';
    let pageURL = null;

    let Draft = ($container, formSelector) => {
        let $form;

        // handlers/listeners
        let handlers = {
            close: () => {
                // back to inbox
            },
            submit: () => {
                // save and show previw
            },
            // ...
        }

        let init = () => {
            $form = $container.find(formSelector);
            // widgets...
            // initialize "pluggable" handlers
            Object.values(handlers).forEach(handler => handler());
        }

        return {
            init: () => {...},
            requestAndLoad: () => {...},
            submit: () => {...},
            // expose handlers
            handlers: () => handlers,
        }
    }

    return {
        init: () => {...},
        load: () => requestAndLoad(pageURL),
        setURL: url => pageURL = url,
        getURL: () => pageURL,
        getName: () => name,
        // expose Draft
        Draf: Draft
    }
})();

let Users = (function () {
    let DraftModal = ($container, formSelector) => {
        const base = Emails.Draft($container, formSelector);
        // "override" base handlers
        delete base.handlers.close;
        // post a different submit handler
        base.handlers.submit: () => {...};
        return form;
    }
})();
```

I have a original `Draft` object with the original behavior, exposing `handlers` so that they can be changed from an outerscope therefore defining a different behavior with the new `DraftModal` object which acts as a wrapper. I'm not familiar with patterns, but this looks like a decorator?

Anyway, again, it seems like a bad idea and awkward solution.

Any tips would be welcome.

Comment: Just curious - does it have to be javascript? What about something like Typescript and a framework like Angular? They seem to impose quite a good structure/architecture.

Comment: @esc_space introducing a new framework would set us back way too far at this point. I have to work with what I have.

Comment: Do you compulsory have to use js to do that? I mean you can use angular for that, angular will provide you more performance and it will be easy to implement SPA.